# error: macro "curl_easy_setopt" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 3

Tags: c++, curl

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com/ip=%d&port=%d&time=%d", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
```

my error:

> macro "curl_easy_setopt" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 3

please, help

Comment: As the error message says,  [`curl_easy_setopt` takes exactly 3 arguments](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html). Remove all the extra `argv[...]`s.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `curl_easy_setopt` is

```
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLoption option, parameter);
```

if you would like to create your `parameter` string based on `argv` then you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

```
#include <format>

std::string url = std::format("example.com/ip={}&port={}&time={}", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

Comment: repeat in c# please

Comment: @alexshved Then why did you tag your question in C++?